# How to dump mysql database with applescript

Tags: applescript, mysql

I use mysql with zend.
I'd like to do an apple script to backup one database on a specific folder.

I know how to do in php but not with applescript.

See below my script in PHP.

```
    <?php
require_once ('../MySQL.php');
require_once ('../conf.php');
include('../functions.php');

echo '----------------- Dump mySQL-----------------<br>';

$NameFile=DB_DATABASE . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql';
$backupFile =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/MySoft/backup/'.$NameFile;

$commandMac = '/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h '.DB_HOST.' -u '.DB_USER.' -p'.DB_PWD.' -B '.DB_DATABASE.'>'. $backupFile;

system($commandMac);


?>
```

So could you help me to do the same with applescript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple method would be to run the php script from applescript. Something like this would work...

```
set phpScriptPath to "/path/to/phpscript"
do shell script "php -q " & quoted form of POSIX path of phpScriptPath
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the easiest way

```
    set shellScript to "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump DatabaseToDump > FileWhereToDump.sql"
do shell script shellScript
```

This approach, which uses shell scripting only and should work with a local MySQL.
DatabaseToDump being the database you wish to dump and FileWhereToDump.sql the target.